# Scroll to an ID minus some pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have below code already and working well to scroll down to the ID ('expressRate') on page loading. But with change of requirement the page should scroll down to a point 50 pixels above the div ID 'expressRate'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $location.hash('expressRate');
 $anchorScroll();
```

Comment: Get the vertical http://api.jquery.com/offset/ , subtract 50, and http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2 the window down to it.

Answer (score 3):

try this javascript code after you scroll to the tag 'expressRate'

```
window.location('#expressRate');
window.scrollBy(0,-50);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//get the element
var $expressRate = $('#expressRate');
//get the vertical distance of the element from the top of the page
var verticalPositionOfElement = $expressRate.offset().top;

//added a timeout just so you could see the start and then the
//adjustment
setTimeout(function () {
  //scroll the window down the element distance, minus whatever
  $(window).scrollTop(verticalPositionOfElement - 50);
}, 1000);
```

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 5000px;
}

#expressRate {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-top: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="expressRate">
```

Comment: I have tried your code and found it's working fine, also I appreciate your comments on each line of the code which helped me a lot. Thank you.

Thank you all for your quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById("expressRate")) - 50);

    function findPos(obj) {
        var curtop = 0;
        if (obj.offsetParent) {
            do {
                curtop += obj.offsetTop;
            } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return [curtop];
        }
    }
```

Comment: The findPos function returns the value of that div postion in window and if you need to scroll 50 pixel above then you can directly do the same with above code..